# Square Root inaccurate in decimals python

Tags: python-3.x

Why does decimal points show inaccurate square root? It must be all zeros perfectly.

```
print('Enter your input:')
n = input()

def squareroot(n):
        i = 0.01
        while i*i < float(n):
                i += 0.01
        return i

print (squareroot(n))
```

output -

```
Enter your input:
100
10.009999999999831

Enter your input:
25
5.009999999999938

Enter your input:
9
3.00999999999998
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm amounts to "repeatedly increase `i` by 0.01 until `i*i` is bigger than `n`". If `x` is the true square root, this will return a number between `x` and `x+.01`, which is exactly what you're seeing. If you want a more accurate answer, pick a smaller increment or (better yet) use a better algorithm, like 
[binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) or [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number). Or, if this isn't a homework assignment, just use `math.sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the values of binary floating point numbers are approximated when it is not a power of 2.

`0.1` represented in the standard `binary64` format is actually exactly `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` in decimal. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for detailed explanations.

To avoid the inherit inaccuracies of binary floating point numbers you can either use the `decimal` module, or in your case, simply increment `i` by a number that's a power of 2 instead, such as `0.0078125`, which is `2 ** -7`.

```
def squareroot(n):
    i = 0.0078125
    while i * i < float(n):
        i += 0.0078125
    return i
```

Sample input/output after this change:

```
Enter your input:
25
5.0
```